# circle with conical gradient in android

Tags: android

**Does anyone knows h!ow can I set conical gradient in android?
Like in this picture:**

http://www.astutegraphics.com/images/blog/tutorials/how_to_create_true_gears_18_oct_2011/29.png

Answer (score 3):

Sure, use a [SweepGradient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SweepGradient.html), then draw a circle with on a canvas.
An example can be found [here](http://android-er.blogspot.de/2012/09/example-of-paintsetshader-with.html). Have fun!

If you don't need too many colors, you can also define it via xml:

**/res/drawable/sweepgradient.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        a:shape="oval"
        a:dither="true">

    <gradient a:type="sweep"
            a:startColor="#FFFF0000"
            a:centerColor="#FF0000FF"
            a:endColor="#FF00FF00" />

</shape>
```

A SweepGradient is a native component so you cannot rely on Javas comfortable stacktraces. If you get non-stacktrace errors first check all native components.

Here is a quick example:

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.SweepGradient;
    import android.view.View;

    public class GradientView extends View {

    // Edit these values as you want!
    private static int[] mColors={Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE};

    private Paint mPaint=new Paint();
    private boolean mSetShader=false;

    public GradientView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float cX=getWidth()/2F, cY=getHeight()/2F;

        if (!mSetShader) {
            mPaint.setShader(new SweepGradient(cX, cY, mColors, null));
            mSetShader=true;
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(cX, cY, Math.min(cX, cY), mPaint);
    }

}
```

Note that you may wan't to recreate the SweepGradient if the center changes (if the view resizes). I left out additional constructors and onMeasure for simplicity...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm new to android.. Could you suggest how can I make gradient exact like in an image above?  I have to add second gradient?

Comment: You don't have to add a second gradient, in your case I'd recommend to go the programmatic way (no xml). Just look at the example (the link) and provide an array of (int) colors as the third parameter.